# How to cross compile to an old i486/i586 architecture (Vortex86DX)

Tags: compiling, c++, cross-compilation

I need to cross compile to Vortex86DX. It seens to have a i486/i586 architecure.

What packages is needed to install on Ubuntu ?

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32783889/vortex86dx-illegal-instruction-on-c-code-toolchain-build), just asking the compiler to `-match=i586` doesn´t work as the libraries seens to be i686 built.

PS: I need support to C++11 (-std0x), so I need a gcc compiler that undestands that standard.

Thanks for helping.